# Python: Store decorator in a class?

Tags: python, class, python-decorators

My decorator is working nice and well, and now stored in a module. If possible I'd like to store it in a **class** instead where it will sit with related functions. However, I can't seem to get it to work, this is the code (without the irrelevant parts):

```
class MqPubSubFwdController(object):

    def __init__(self, address, port_pub, port_sub):

        self.mq_path_list = []
        self.mq_path_func = {}

    def handle_mq(self, mq_path, cmd=None):
        """ Decorator function.
            Registers the MQ path
        """
        def decorator(fn):
            key = "my_key"
            self.mq_path_list.append(prepostfix(mq_path).lower())
            self.mq_path_func[key] = fn

            def decorated(*args,**kwargs):
                return fn(*args,**kwargs)
            return decorated
        return decorator

@messaging.handle_mq('/mode/set','PUT')
def mq_mode_set(path=None, cmd=None, args=None, data=None):
    """ Set mode """
    print "A MODE WAS SET"
    return "A MODE WAS SET"

messaging = MqPubSubFwdController('localhost',1,2)
```

This returns the error *NameError: name 'messaging' is not defined* on the @-decorator. Is there a way to make it work so that I can call the decorator function when located in the class? I'm on Python 2.7.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? *How* doesn't it work? Does it throw an error? Does it make your PC catch fire?

Comment: "This doesn't work.". How does it fail?

Comment: Once I defined a placeholder function `dispatcher_key`, this ran perfectly fine when I tested it.

Comment: The error I get when I run your code is "name DEFAULT_PORT_PUB is not defined". Then "name dispatcher_key is not defined". Then "name prepostfix is not defined". Are those the errors you're asking about? Probably not. If you want us to help you, you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Rewritten to be Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable. The problem is on the @messaging decorator line. I can't get it to work when the decorator is within the class.

Comment: Obviously you have to instantiate `messaging` **before** you try to use it as a decorator.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, I don't think it's obvious, but it was indeed the issue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Aran-Fey said, it's about the location.
The class needs to be initialized before you can reference the decorator function inside it.

This is the correct code:

```
class MqPubSubFwdController(object):

    def __init__(self, address, port_pub, port_sub):

        self.mq_path_list = []
        self.mq_path_func = {}

    def handle_mq(self, mq_path, cmd=None):
        """ Decorator function.
            Registers the MQ path
        """
        def decorator(fn):
            key = "my_key"
            self.mq_path_list.append(mq_path.lower())
            self.mq_path_func[key] = fn

            def decorated(*args,**kwargs):
                return fn(*args,**kwargs)
            return decorated
        return decorator

messaging = MqPubSubFwdController('localhost',1,2)

@messaging.handle_mq('/mode/set','PUT')
def mq_mode_set(path=None, cmd=None, args=None, data=None):
    """ Set mode """
    print "A MODE WAS SET"
    return "A MODE WAS SET"
```